# Can't get php to set sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session, http-post, session-variables

I just can't get to set sessions in php, and I can't find the reason why.

Hope you can give me a clue, on where I might be doing something wrong!

index.php

```
<?php
    // Inialize session
    session_start();

    include_once("commons/config.php");
    $authenticated = checkLoggedIn("yes", FALSE);
    //flushMemberSession();

    var_dump($authenticated);

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
... followed by html and some php ifs
```

jquery ajax call WHICH RETURNS **TRUE** or **FALSE**, as it should, from `checkPass()` inside `actions.php`

```
$('#login').click(function(){
    var data = $('#login-form').serialize();
    $.post('commons/actions.php', data, function(result){
        if(result == true){
            console.log(result);
            //location.reload();
        }else{
            console.log('not authenthicated');
        }
    },'json');
    return false;
});
```

actions.php

```
session_start();
if (!$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Unauthorized', true, 400);
    exit;
} else {

    include('config.php');

    $user = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username']));
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['password']));

    $response = checkPass($user, $pass); // false or

    $debug = array('user'=>$user, 'pass'=>$pass, 'response'=>$response);

    print_r(json_encode($response));

}
```

functions:

```
function checkLoggedIn($status, $redirect=TRUE){
    switch($status){
        case "yes":
            if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedIn"])){
                if($redirect) {
                    header("Location: login.php");
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $authenticated = false;
                    return $authenticated;
                }
            } else {
                checkLoggedIn("no");
            }
        break;
        case "no":
            if(isset($_SESSION["loggedIn"]) && $_SESSION["loggedIn"] === true ){
                //header("Location: members.php");
                $authenticated = true;
                return $authenticated;
            }
        break;
    }   
    return true;
}

function checkPass($username, $password) {
    $query="SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($query, $link) or die("checkPass fatal error: ".mysql_error());

// Check exactly one row is found:
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1) {
    cleanMemberSession($username);
    return true;
    /*$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $row;*/
}
//Bad username:
return false;
}

function cleanMemberSession($username) {
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION["username"]=$username;
$_SESSION["loggedIn"]=true;
session_write_close();
}
```

### UPDATE

AJAX Headers

```
Response Headers
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  4
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Sun, 27 May 2012 19:36:54 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Server  Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.8
Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  31
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  PHPSESSID=qhbjq76f4np7iug09jrnl4j5j1
Host    localhost
Referer http://localhost/tw/Tevienes/web/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

### UPDATE2

BTW, the response to `var_dump($_SESSION);` is `array(0) { }`

### UPDATE3

I just added `$_SESSION['test'] = 'alex';` after `session_start();` in index.php, and the session variable has been set... so It must be something with the function setting the variables... or who know what else

Comment: You forgot to describe what you expected and what you get (an error message, wrong result etc.)

Comment: I expect it to set SESSION variables, but nothing

Comment: please post the ajax `POST` headers and data and the ajax response.

Comment: @Quassnoi, I just updated my question with the headers, it seams ok, no?

Comment: btw, the ajax response headers is after I clicked loggin with correct credentials

Comment: Have you got a session start in actions.php?

Comment: in actions.php no, I have it in index.php... I'm going to set it now and test

Comment: I just added to `actions.php` (first line after `<?php`) also, still no effect... BTW, the response to `var_dump($_SESSION)` is `array(0) {
}`

Comment: so the issue must be somewhere in the function... check the question's update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put session_start() in all called .php files, also the ones called from ajax.
Also at the start of actions.php put parentheses on the comparisons. ! operator has higher precedence than < or >.

change

```
 if (!$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
```

to

```
 if (!($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
```

Comment: I'm sure you know this but to other readers, if a session has already been started, calling session_start simply resumes the previously started session.

Comment: @w0rldart I don't see a session_start() in actions.php

Comment: @sivann, your edit has no logic in it... and that wasn't the problem... thanks any way... I think I've solved the problem. Your edit has nothing to compare to, it should be: `if (!(x)==(y))`

Comment: What was it then? I think you really need the parentheses. otherwise it is like if ( (!x) == (y) )

Answer (score 0):

Long shot and silly, but check that the date and time is set correctly on both the server and client.  If either is set in the incorrectly, the session cookie will/might not get set.